# VNC Session with specific resolution

Tags: solaris, vnc

I have a machine running Solaris 10, I can successfully start a remote VNC session, but I can't set the resolution of the session, I know that the GPU is capable of much higher resolutions than the one used in the VNC session, but I can't find any settings or info about this. Im using TightVNC Viewer on a PC as client

When I connect a monitor to the machine running Solaris xrandr gives me this:

```
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1600 x 1200, maximum 1600 x 1200
default connected 1600x1200+0+0 0mm x 0mm
1600x1200        61.0*
1280x1024        60.0
1440x900         60.0
1280x800         60.0
1024x768         61.0
800x600          61.0
640x480          61.0
```

1440x900 is the native resolution of the build in LCD on the Solaris machine.

I have tried using xrandr to set the resolution, after starting the VNC session, but this gives me:

```
The Server does not support the XRandrR extension.
Runtime resolution changes to the display size are not available
```

So I guess my question is: How do I start a X screen/display with a resolution other than the native resolution? so I can connect to this screen/display using VNC? I don't expect the machine to be able to display this screen on the build-in LCD, I just want to be able to access the other screen/display with the higher resolution using VNC

The Solaris machine is running xvnc

Comment: Not sure about Solaris, but it seems that [`Xvnc`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/Xvnc.1.en) in TigerVNC allows you to specify the geometry. And apparently you can/should set the it in [`$HOME/.vnc/config`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/vncsession.8.en). Personally I just start Xvfb manually and attach x11vnc to it. "Modern" versions of Xvfb supports XRandR and allows me to add mode and change mode with `xrandr` after it has started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I found this: https://blogs.oracle.com/solaris/post/vnc-made-simple the vncadm script is all I needed, with it I can specify a virtual screen with resolution, and I can connect to it using VNC client. You will have to use Wayback machine to grab the script, its the last link at the bottom of the page "vncadm was written by my collegue Ralph Bogendoerfer.  You can download it here. "